# Libreoffice upgrade (7.5 to 7.6) broke my macro

Tags: macros, libreoffice, basic, calc

The macro was working perfectly under 7.5 (7.5.3??) but very frustratingly it's now dead after a Libreoffice 7.6.0.3 upgrade, as are the many(!) instances / slight variants of this code through my sheet. Can someone please help me understand why the old code isn't valid anymore and give a suggestion how to repair it?
(Ideally the macro should work under version 7.0 onwards for different machines.)

```
Sub Col_D_for_Y
sheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
    source = sheet.getCellRangeByName("D14:D32")
    target = sheet.getCellRangeByName("L14")
    sheet.copyRange(target.CellAddress, source.RangeAddress)
End Sub
```

The `source = sheet.getCellRangeByName("D14:D32")` code is highlighted
when the error message box pops up.

[image]

Comment: Just assume that the word Source has become a reserved word and now means something different to BASIC than you had in mind. Add a variable description of the form `Dim Sheet, Source, Target` to the beginning of the procedure and try again

Comment: Hi JohnSUN. I did a global Find and Replace of "source" to "MySource" (86 entries!) and it all  works now. I actually read the release notes before upgrading and I didn't notice any mention about source becoming a reserved word, so I would probably only have discovered this 'fix' after much gnashing of teeth, so I am really thankful - yet again - for your assistance.
I've not dimmed my variables to save time and I got away with it.

Comment: @JohnSUN: Do you have any links that mention this? I searched but couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: @JimK No, I don't have a link - I was just making a guess when I saw the error message "no RangeAddress property"